# After 3rd party login verification, unable to access element using selenium Javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, autocomplete

```
const {Builder, By, Key, util} = require("selenium-webdriver");
let { email, pass } = require("./credentials.json");
async function example() {
    try {
        let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("firefox").build();
        await driver.get("https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=28:d37f235b-2f62-4827-ae12-a26b657a2cbb");
        await driver.findElement(By.id("openTeamsClientInBrowser")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("loginfmt")).sendKeys(email);
        driver.findElement(By.id("idSIButton9")).click();

        await driver.get("https://fs.liu.se/adfs/ls/?client-request-id=a515d558-aed8-4c16-9896-d97043e38389&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3afederation%3aMicrosoftOnline&wctx=LoginOptions%3D3%26estsredirect%3d2%26estsrequest%3drQIIAeNiNdQz0LPUYjbUM7RSMU01Tk41SzbQNUoyTNM1MbIw1bVIMUnSNTdNTTW3AEJjE7MiIS6BiKuiS2-sE_OZMe1mgfPj5s5ZjAyrGOUySkoKiq309UtSE3OL9XIzk4vyi_PTSvSS83P10_N3MDJeYGR8wci4ikkl0cQk1TDVyEzXMtE4RdfEJMUAaE-Ssa6ZuZmhkblBipGBaeotJn5_x9KSDCMQkV-UWZU6i1nFMjEtySDZwlLX3MIwWdfEwNBQN8kY5N4UE9MkM9OkJFMLo03MbEAbc_PzbjAzPmIWzy3NyCw2NTR0KC4pTUnNK9HLySzVK069wML4ikWMg1GAQYJTgUGD3YDZioODC8hjUGD4wcK4iBXoTe2m7pBdB1e5LF-1x69KTY7hFKu-r2FKsYebQX6Eq2G5fq5lalZAWYhfSG6YUZJXeEZIeplniatppKdRRJ5RqK2FleEENrZTbExexR_YGDvYGXZxEgijW1wiRgZGBrpAbxkZKxiaWxkaWpmYRR3gZQAA0&cbcxt=&username=muhis511%40student.liu.se&mkt=&lc=");
        driver.findElement(By.name("Password")).sendKeys(pass);
        await driver.findElement(By.id("submitButton")).click();
        
        await driver.findElement(By.id("send-message-button")).click();

    }catch(Exception) {

    } finally {
        await driver.quit();
    }
}
example();
```

after successfull login await driver.findElement(By.id("send-message-button")).click(); this line not working. also it takes 30, 40 sec to load team chat.

Comment: After clicking submit, you'll want to use a webdriverwait to wait for something to be in the DOM that tells you that you are logged in.   (it'll take a little time to login and right now you're not waiting for anything...)

Comment: Can you write the line of code. because it's not working I tried different wait commands. also, I am getting a warning (Unhandled rejection mode).

Comment: Maybe check for the message input to be available?  ExpectedConditions are here:  https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html